# Error getting joined data with AngularFire2 and Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2, angularfire2

My database consists of two 'tables' with messages and users, with the messages having an senderID that matches an userID. I am using the following code to join these two together when fetching the data

```
this.messages = this.af.database.list(`/messages/1`)
    .map(messages => {
      messages.map(message => {
        this.af.database.object('users/' + message.sender)
          .subscribe(user => {
            message.userdata = user;
            console.log(message);
          });
        return message;
      });
      return messages;
    });
```

console.log on the message shows the structure I am after, however, when i use `{{item.userdata.provider.displayName}}` it gives me the following `TypeError: Cannot read property 'provider' of undefined`

Thankful for advice.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but does `messages.map` not return the mapped values? You don't appear to be returning that, but rather, just the original messages object.

Answer (score 1):

You can't depend on message.userdata being populated. You're making an asynchronous call to fetch the data from the server, but not waiting for all of the users to be downloaded before rendering your UI.

Additionally, you should consider the case that a user may not exist. So you won't be able to use `{{item.userdata.provider.displayName}}` without at least an trying `item.userdata?` first.

I'd guess there's a much better way to go about this, such as creating an `item.getUserName()` method that can handle these implementation details a bit more transparently and elegantly.